# okhttp throws exception in response

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to fetch JSON data but don't know why the response throws exception.

```
Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
        Request request=new Request.Builder().url(datastes).build();
        Response httpresponse=client.newCall(request).execute();
        stringdata=httpresponse.body().string();
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to throw an exception? And which exception?

Comment: JB_Nizet@sry for the typo mistake!!

Comment: You should post the exception message or any logcat info that you got.

Comment: thanks for your time and help guys ... the code is working well with out making any changes ..... i guess the problem was some were else ...